# gitk do not show the diff anymore. (Local changes checked in to index but not committed)

Tags: git, gitk

I can use the gitk tool to view the current changes that have do not committed yet.

But when I update the git from `2.29.2.windows.3` to `2.33.0.windows.2`

**diff is gone**. only show

> [Local changes checked in to index but not committed](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e2b9cb1c5a45290f568681862fb27714d6e4e52b/gitk-git/gitk#L5366-L5382)

[image]

---

I don't know what happened. I tried to read the [release note](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) but couldn't find the answer.

---

I'm not sure if this is related to the following changes

last commit: 2020/09/11: [gitk: replace tabs tith spaces](https://github.com/git/git/blame/e2b9cb1c5a45290f568681862fb27714d6e4e52b/gitk-git/gitk#L5367-L5374)

---

I don't want to use any replacement tools (like using [git gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) to view changes); I want [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk/) to work as well as it used to.

Comment: Do you have unstaged changes ? In a terminal, what does `git status -s` show ? Does `git diff` display anything ?

Comment: Hi @LeGEC, It show `new file: .gitmodules`, `modified:  README.md`, ... and neither one show the diff, but it does work in 2.29.2

Comment: This is a regression (bug) in `git-diff-index` that will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @j6t, Thank you for getting back to me so quickly and giving me an answer.

Comment: I am very new to the git forum. If anyone wants to have a deeper understanding of git, 
I think it would be helpful to join some discussions. Here are some links I found
● https://git-scm.com/community
● [git-for-windows/issues](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues)
● [groups.google](https://groups.google.com/g/git-users/)
● [marc.info/?l=git](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=163103876304855&w=2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [j6t noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336909/gitk-do-not-show-the-diff-anymore-local-changes-checked-in-to-index-but-not-co#comment122551166_69336909), this is a bug in the current versions of Git, scheduled to be fixed in an upcoming release.

Technically, the issue has to do with `gitk` using the `--cc` option every time.  This used to work for `git diff-index`, with the `--cc` being ignored when the index is not in conflicted state, and the `--cc` producing a combined diff when the index *is* in a conflicted state (i.e., when you have an unresolved merge).  Now `git diff-index --cc` produces an error message and quits, and `gitk` thinks that this means there are no unstaged changes.

(The `--cc` option to `git diff-index` was never documented and was accidentally removed, instead of becoming documented.  This shows why it's dangerous to depend on undocumented behavior: you can't tell if it was intended.  It probably was, in this case, but the person who improved `git diff` handling for merges didn't know this.)

Comment: Thanks, I localy edited my gitk script and removed any reference to `--cc` and it now works again. Probably displayed wrong for conflicts, but I don’t use gitk when there are conflicts, only command line.

Answer (score 3):

git 2.33.1 has fixed this problem.

> [Recent "diff -m" changes broke "gitk", which has been corrected.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/af6d1d6/Documentation/RelNotes/2.33.1.txt#L81)